# adding class and font style to html and return html jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am getting HTML text where I want to add bootstrap class after finding tags. String can have multiple tags and I want to add font tag with important

Lets for example I got string

```
var temp = "<div><table id='m' class='f'></table><table></table></div>";
table = $('table', temp).addClass('table-responsive').css('color', 'red!important').css('font-family', 'FS Lola,Arial,sans-serif!important');
```

**But I don't how I will return above html after changing style and font to render**

> My requirement is that string is coming dynamic and then i want to add
>   class to certain element and then font style, After all this I want to
>   render this HTML in div

Comment: What do you mean by "how will I return above html"?

Comment: `table = $('table', temp);` seems incorrect also as `var temp = "<div>...</div>"`. You have a DIV inside your table?

Comment: @JerdineSabio than how can I find table element and add class to table

Comment: Just append your HTML to the DOM. e.g. `$("body").append(table);`

Comment: @MarioVázquez My requirement is that string is coming dynamic and then i want to add class to certain element and then font style, After all this I want to render this HTML in div

Comment: Following your code you could go: `table.find("table").css("background", "#F00")` to style a set of elements from your `jQuery` object, and use the appropiated method to render the `HTML` (`append`, `after`, `before`, etc.)

Comment: @MarioVázquez If you don't mind kindly can you give me sample code. If working than I will mark as answer please

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Need space between !important

```
css('color', 'red !important').css('font-family', 'FS Lola,Arial,sans-serif !important')
```

Comment: that is not my problem is that how I will return html doing all this.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is always rendered first. So in my code, initially the font color is blue.

jquery can't seem to modify the css color property because it can't add an important suffix. So using the code `$("table").css("color","red !important");` **doesn't work**.

What I ended up doing is modifying the javascript object. Once you've selected the table using `$("table");` you could access its javascript object by index [0]; `$("table")[0];`.

**The complete script to modify an !important css would be;**

```
$("table")[0].style.setProperty( 'color', 'red', 'important' );
```

**To add a class, simply do**;

```
// you don't need the second argument $("table", "somethingElse"). You only need the $("table")
$("table").addClass("className");
```

Try my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var t = $("table");
  
  // jquery doesn't work
  // $("table").css("color","red");
  
  // using javascript function does work, select the javascript object via [0] index
  t[0].style.setProperty( 'color', 'red', 'important' );
  t[0].style.setProperty( 'font-family', 'FS Lola,Arial,sans-serif', 'important' );
});
```

```css
table{
  border:1px solid black;
  color:blue !important;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

table th, table td{
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element using `jQuery` like so:

```
var table = $("<table id='m' class='f'></table>")
```

Now the table exists in memory as a `jQuery` object but it hasn't been rendered to the page yet. You can operate with the table dynamically, for example adding a `tr`:

```
table.append($("<tr>"));
```

or adding a class:

```
table.addClass("class_name");
```

Now we can add it to the page. Suppose you want to put it inside the body of your page. You can do it as follows:

```
$("body").append(table);
```

You could added it to a `div` with `id=whatever` instead:

```
$("#whatever").append(table);
```

**EDIT** based on your requirement:

```
var temp = $("<div><table id='m' class='f'></table><table></table></div>");
temp.find("table").addClass('table-responsive').css('color', 'red!important').css('font-family', 'FS Lola,Arial,sans-serif!important');
$("body").append(temp);
```

Comment: Hi, This is not my requirement. I will explain you again. I have string of HTML in memory, it can have table or div in that HTML, I want to find all table add class and I also want to add style than I want to render that HTML

Comment: @Milind, please see the edit in my answer. Please provide a working code snippet to modify if it's not clear enought.